# Inconsistency between a continuous and a discrete version of a stochastic process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, discrete-calculus

Consider an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck stochastic process $(r_t)_{t\geq 0}$ given through the SDE:
$$dr_t=\kappa \left( \mu-r_t\right)dt+\sigma dW_t,$$
where $r_0, \kappa, \mu$ and $\sigma$ are given positive constants.

It is known that it is a Gaussian process in a sense that
$$r_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(e^{-\kappa t} \left( r_0 -\mu \right)+\mu , \frac{\sigma^2}{2 \kappa} \left(  1-e^{-2\kappa t} \right)\right).$$

The algorithm for its simulation given as
$$ r(t_{i+1})=e^{-\kappa \left( t_{i+1}-t_i\right)} \left( r(t_i)-\mu\right)+\mu +\sigma \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \kappa}\left(  1-e^{-2 \kappa \left(t_{i+1}-t_t \right)} \right)}Z_{i+1}, $$
where $Z_{i+1}$ is a standard normal, is an exact simulation in a sense that the distribution of the $r(t_1), \dots, r(t_n)$ it produces is precisely that of the process at times $t_1, \dots, t_n$ for the same value of $r_0$.

There is something that's kinda puzzling to me about this, and don't know how to state it mathematically precisely, so apologies in advance.

Namely, if we assume that at some given time $t$ we have 
$$\mu-r_t>0,$$
i.e.
$$ \mu>r_t,$$
 looking at the SDE it's obvious that the drift term is positive, and the bigger the parameter $\kappa$, the bigger the drift term $\kappa (\mu-r_t)$ is, thus implying that the probability of $r_{t+\Delta t}>\mu$ is increasing with $\kappa$.

On the other hand, if we look at the simulation algorithm when $\mu-r_t>0$, if $\kappa$ is increasing the (negative) term $e^{-\kappa \Delta t} \left( r_t-\mu\right)$ is getting closer to zero from the left, so

$$ e^{-\kappa \Delta t} \left( r_t-\mu\right)+\mu \to \mu_-, $$
but also the std of the random variable $\sigma \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \kappa}\left(  1-e^{-2 \kappa \Delta t} \right)}Z_{i+1}$ is getting smaller, so the probability of $r_{t+\Delta t}>\mu$ is I guess also kinda increasing with $\kappa$, but on the intuitive level it seems to me like it's not the same rate of increase? Like, when considering big $\kappa$ and the SDE - it looks like the probability of $r_t>\mu$ is quite large, but looking at the algorithm the bigger $\kappa$ will make us closer to the mean but we won't cross it with the drift part, and then the stochastic part is getting "less and less" stochastic, so there's less chance we're gonna cross $\mu$ actually.

My question is kinda all over the place, apologies for that. Would greatly appreciate any insights on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Namely, if we assume that at some given time t we have
>   $$ \mu−r_t>0, $$
>   i.e.
>   $$ \mu>r_t, $$
>   looking at the SDE it's obvious that the drift term is positive, and the bigger the parameter $\kappa$, the bigger the drift term $\kappa(\mu−r_t)$ is,

So, $r_t$ is *below* the mean, and the SDE is saying that it should be increasing, ie., moving towards the mean from the left.  This is consistent with what you've written about the simulation/solution.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I'm still kinda confused - maybe this will explain my confusion a little bit better. It seems to me when looking at the SDE that there is some $\kappa$ big enough for which we can be almost sure that the next value of $r_t$ will go above the mean (since $\kappa$ doesn't influence the diffusion term at all). On the other hand, looking at the simulation algorithm it seems as for any $\kappa$, no matter how big it is, we can never be completely sure that the next short rate value will go above the mean (because the deterministic part doesn't "take" as above the mean).

Comment: Not sure if this makes any sense, I am sure that I'm overlooking something but it just seems weird to me and I'd like to realize the error in my reasoning.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now.  I think the problem is that you're thinking of the SDE in terms of discrete steps of time as well, which it isn't.  It's written for continuous time, which means that the meaningful info from the $f(r)dt$ term is the 'direction' that $f(r)$ is pointing - it doesn't matter how big the value of $\kappa$ is, the next point in time is infinitely close!  I can edit some more details into my answer using an ODE example if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks once again @KevinG. I had a feeling that this confusion has to be somehow related to my wrong intuition about continuum! :) If you find enough time to do that, it would be great. Thanks for your effort in any case.